# Best practices for using person accounts within a managed package

Tags: managed-package, person-accounts

I have enabled person accounts in my org and have a requirement of creating a managed package. This package concentrates on person accounts and several other custom objects. I found that we cannot reference person accounts fields directly if we are going to create a managed package as users will not have enabled person accounts in their org.

> I would like to know the best practices to be followed when using person accounts with managed package with respect to coding and configuration and also any limitation that might arise later due to the use of person accounts in managed package.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My colleague wrote this article [Invoke Contact triggers logic on Person Accounts](http://force746.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/invoke-contact-triggers-logic-on-person-accounts/) that discusses one problem area.

Comment: Are you using the Non Profit Starter Pack? I think it probably serves as a best practice example for how to handle person accounts using it's relationships model. Check out their code on Github.

Comment: I am using a partner developer edition

Answer (score -1):

No worries from Winter15 onwards you can package PA.  [Winter15 Release Notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_development_additional.htm)

Comment: I dont think this is the answer. It looks like comment.